# Strange behviour while parsing command line arguments c++

Tags: c++, command-line, pipe

here is an issue I have never seen before and thought it would be share-worthy. Im not sure why it happens though.

This is how I invoke my program:

> ./foo -switch1 arg1 -switch2 arg2 -switch3 arg3|arg4|arg5 -switch4 -arg6

Each switch is used to indicate a different type of argument and I parse them accordingly.

The problem occurs with switch3, which indicates that `arg3`, `arg4`, `arg5` all correspond to the same switch and are delineated using the `|` character.

For some reason, I can run the program perfectly, but when I try to debug it using gdb, My program crashes with a `during startup, program exited with code 127` error.

Here's what intrigues me. It also says `bin/bash: arg4 not found`. It takes the argument right after the first `|` character, which now I assume it perceives as the pipe character, and tries to invoke a bash script.

Why does this happen??? Doesn't the compiler take the entire command line string and consider space separated tokens as different arguments? Why is the `|` being interpreted differently? I tried adding `arg3|arg4|arg5` in inverted quotes `""`, and it works fine. I also tried separating them by `-`, eg. `arg3-arg4-arg5`, and this works fine too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Comment: "Doesn't the compiler take the entire command line string" - what does it have to do with the compiler? When you execute the program, it will only receive the arguments that the shell sends it, *after* the shell is done parsing it and the pipe symbol has special meaning to the shell. It works with quotes because that tells the shell not to try to parse it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the shell is responsible of passing the arguments to the executable. Ill look this up.

Answer (score 7):

The `|` character has a special meaning in `bash`: it creates a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29).

Your program only sees the following arguments:

```
./foo -switch1 arg1 -switch2 arg2 -switch3 arg3
```

The `|arg4` syntax is interpreted by `bash` to mean that the (non-existent) `arg4` command should be run, and that the standard output of `./foo` should be piped into the standard input of `arg4`. The `|arg5 ...` is interpreted in the same manner.

To suppress this behaviour, run your program like so:

```
./foo -switch1 arg1 -switch2 arg2 -switch3 'arg3|arg4|arg5' -switch4 -arg6
```

(note the quotes).

Comment: Yep. Thats what I eventually figured. Counter question:   Is there a difference between ./foo arg1 arg2 | some_other_executable and ./foo arg1|some_other_executable arg2?? Does arg2 get passed to some_other_executable in this case here?

Comment: @SreemanananthSadanand There is a difference, in the second one arg2 will be passed to the other executable e.g. `echo arg1 | perl -e'print "My arg1: $ARGV[0]\n" ;  while(<STDIN>){ print $_; }' arg2`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `|` is a pipe so you end up trying to call arg4 which the shell can not find. You need to quote the content in with pipes in them i.e. `"arg3|arg4|arg5"`:

```
./foo -switch1 arg1 -switch2 arg2 -switch3 "arg3|arg4|arg5" -switch4 -arg6
```

If you are curious you can check out [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). If you are not doing a lot of shell programming you may not see these problems often but when you do it may take you a while to figure out what is going on so learning more about shell programming can be helpful in the long term. I remember hitting number 3 and it took me a while to find a good solution the first time.

Comment: +1: Yep not too much of a shell programmer. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @SreemanananthSadanand Any other questions or this answer acceptable?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Oh Im sorry, I should have made a mention that my answer got replied. You may close and archive this thread. Thank you.